# Why Implementation for is_copy_assignable doesn't work?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, copy-assignment

This is my attempt at an implementation for is_copy_assignable:

```
template<typename, typename = void>
struct IsCopyAssignable : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct IsCopyAssignable<T, decltype(std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type = std::add_lvalue_reference<const T>::type, void())> : std::true_type
{};
```

It was a failure.

Here's the test cases:

```
int main()
{
    struct Structure {};
    std::cout << "IsCopyAssignable=\n";
    std::cout << IsCopyAssignable<int>::value << '\n'; // should be true
    std::cout << IsCopyAssignable<int&>::value << '\n'; // should be true
    std::cout << IsCopyAssignable<const int&>::value << '\n'; // should be false
    std::cout << IsCopyAssignable<const double&>::value << '\n'; // should be false
    std::cout << IsCopyAssignable<class Structure>::value << '\n'; // should be true
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

They all print false.

(I realized then that declval in combination with the handy void_t - and decltype of course - can be used for things like these instead.) But I still do not understand exactly why this one doesn't work. I think we want to test whether `const T&` can be assigned to `T&` (as the copy assignment operator does). Well, why then?

Comment: `int& = const int&` wouldn't make any sense.  Probably you want to put `std::declval<typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type>()` etc. in there.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That's an answer. Basically, what you noticed is that the specialization always SFINAEs away because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Technically, you might be able to make `IsCopyAssignable<Structure>::value` be true if you made specializations like `template<> struct std::add_lvalue_reference<Structure> { static bool type; };` and similarly for `std::add_lvalue_reference<const Structure>` - though naturally the standard also makes this undefined behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `decltype(std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type = std::add_lvalue_reference<const T>::type, void())` is ill formed for every `T` as `std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type` is actually not a value, but a type.

`std::declval` might help:

You want to check instead expression `std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<const T&>()` is valid.

So

```
template<typename T>
struct IsCopyAssignable<T,
                       decltype(std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<const T&>(), void())>
       : std::true_type
{};
```

Comment: Yes. But, shouldn't we deal with types and not values inside the expression created in the "unevaluated context" of a `decltype`?

Comment: `decltype` return the type of given expression, and value are used in expression, not type. `i = 42` versus `int& = int`.